# parsing two multi-line grep results to a single bash asociative array

Tags: arrays, bash, grep

I'm retrieving filtered text from a group of emails by using these two commands:

1)

```
curl -u$username:$password --silent "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom" |  grep -oPm1 "(?<=<summary>The host is: )(\S+)+" | sed '1d'
```

2)

```
curl -u$username:$password --silent "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom" |  grep -oPm1 "(?<=the serial is\s)(\w+)+" | sed '1d'
```

each one returns:

1)

```
xy36 
xy34 
xy32
xy30 
xy29 
xy28 
xy26
```

2)

```
Xooz4woo
Oyaith4k
AiN7fie4
ongae6Ro
phoh6fiR
Ohfoh0eM
```

and i need that data to be parsed to an associative array in bash, in a way i can do a loop write/read it, and use each entry on my code. The array should be:

```
machines{
{xy36,Xooz4woo}
{xy34 Oyaith4k}
{xy32, AiN7fie4}
{xy30, ongae6Ro}
{xy29, phoh6fiR}
{xy28, Ohfoh0eM}}
```

so i can access it like:

```
echo "${machines[xy36]}"
result: Xooz4woo
```

how can i do that???

Comment: Rather than 2 `curl`s, what does the actual data look like when it comes back? Maybe you could `curl` once and parse from that in a single pass? In the least I would `curl` to a file so you could skip that second redundant network traffic.

Comment: You can test it yourself with any email, just input your Gmail account credentials and remove the greps!

Comment: curl -u$username:$password --silent "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom"

Comment: Use `"https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom"`.

Comment: Also, doesn't work if you have any decent security enabled, even if the password was right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the result of each in an array, then loop over the array indexes.

```
declare -A machines
hosts=($(first command))
serials=($(second command))
for ((i=0; i < ${#hosts[@]}; i++))
do
    machines[${hosts[$i]}]=${serials[$i]}
done
```